# Sencha Framework. Three-column Carousel

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, carousel

I'm newbie on Sencha.
I want to make 3-column vertical carousel. For example, [TMall interface for IPad](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3480160/carousel.png)

Is it possible?

Comment: It doesn't really look like a Sencha carousel but more like 3 lists that scroll together. So yes it is possible (although it might be a bit harder to create the list on the left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you want

```
{
xtype: container,
layout: 'hbox',
items: [
{
xtype: 'carousel',
direction: 'vertical',
...what the carousel should contain
},
{
xtype: 'carousel',
direction: 'vertical',
...what the carousel should contain
},
{
xtype: 'carousel',
direction: 'vertical',
...what the carousel should contain
}
]
}
```

Hope it helps